# Count() on many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have a Students table and a Language table. They form a many to many relationship using a pivot table Languages_Student.

Is there a way of getting the student which has the biggest amount of languages in common with another student?

I'm not quite sure how to combine COUNT() with some kind of select. This is what I'm working with now:

```
select * from students student1
inner join languages_student ls1
    on student1.id = ls1.student_id
inner join languages l1
    on l1.id = ls1.language_id
inner join languages_student ls2
    on l1.id = ls2.language_id
inner join students student2
    on ls2.student_id = student2.id
where student1.id = 65
group by 16
```

I'm trying to get the student with biggest amount of languages in common with the student with id 65.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a self-join.  Join the junction table to itself on the *language* column; then aggregate by the *student* column to get the number in common:

```
select ls.student_id, count(*) as NumInCommon
from languages_student ls join
     languages_student ls65
     on ls.language = ls65.language and ls65.student_id = 65 and
        ls65.student_id <> ls.student_id
group by ls.student_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        select  ls.student_id, count(ls.language_id) as common
        from languages_student ls
        where ls.id in (        
              select  l.id
              from students s
              inner join languages_student ls
              on s.id = ls.student_id
              inner join languages l
              on l.id = ls.language_id
              where s.id = 65 ) 
        order by count(ls.language_id)
```